# vite + react: how do i connect my index.html to the right src file?

Tags: reactjs, vite

I've successfully imported React through Vite. However, I don't understand why my index.html's reference to main.jsx is forcing me to create a new main.jsx instead of opening the one that's already been created in my src folder?

How do I connect my src to the correct main file?

[index.html showing the src="/src/main.jsx"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq8BK.png)
[after clicking on src="/src/main.jsx", a new main.jsx is created instead of opening the referenced one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4oUC.png)

I tried moving the files around and copying and pasting content in my src folder. Maybe I have to do something with my .json files. I really have no idea where to begin.